# Can you suggest an good alternative for multiple inheritance in this case?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

**Summary:** The case below involves using multiple inheritance for inheriting both an extended interface, and implementation for a basic interface.

I used virtual multiple inheritance to put in place the following system:

I have a hierarchy of abstract interfaces:

```
        ICommon                         
       /       \
ISpecific1     ISpecific2
```

As expected, the specific interfaces add functionality over the common functionality derived from ICommon.

I also have classes implementing the interfaces:

- CommonImp (implements the common functionality - ICommon)
- SpecificImp1 (implementing ISpecific1)
- SpecificImp2 (implementing ISpecific2)

The application eventually uses only SpecificImp1 and SpecificImp2.
But CommonImp is required in order to avoid implementing ICommon twice (in SpecificImp1, SpecificImp2).

This means that, e.g., SpecificImp1 needs to inherit ISpecific1 for the whole interface it needs to expose, and CommonImp for the implementation of the common part.
But both ISpecific1 and CommonImp inherit ICommon (one in order to extend the interface, and one for implementation).
Which makes SpecificImp1 inherit indirectly twice from ICommon.
Using virtual inheritance handled the diamond inheritance issue.

This is the minimal reproducible code example:

```
#include <iostream>


struct ICommon
{
    virtual void DoCommon() = 0;
};

struct ISpecific1 : public virtual ICommon
{
    virtual void DoSpecific1() = 0;
};

struct ISpecific2 : public virtual ICommon
{
    virtual void DoSpecific2() = 0;
};



struct CommonImp : public virtual ICommon
{
    virtual void DoCommon() override { std::cout << "CommonImp::DoCommon" << std::endl; }
};

struct SpecificImp1 : public ISpecific1, public CommonImp
{
    virtual void DoSpecific1() override { std::cout << "SpecificImp1::DoSpecific1" << std::endl; }
};

struct SpecificImp2 : public ISpecific2, public CommonImp
{
    virtual void DoSpecific2() override { std::cout << "SpecificImp2::DoSpecific2" << std::endl; }
};



int main()
{
    SpecificImp1 s1;
    s1.DoCommon();
    s1.DoSpecific1();

    SpecificImp2 s2;
    s2.DoCommon();
    s2.DoSpecific2();

    return 0;
}
```

This design serves me well so far, but it's quite cumbersome.
And multiple inheritance is always something you should consider alternatives for.

So, my question is, given this system, can you suggest a good alternative?

BTW - All types above are structs with everything public. This was done to make the code shorter, please ignore it.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the "Specific" interfaces to inherit from `ICommon`. I also don't see a reason for `CommonImp` (at least not in the very simple example shown in your question). Finally, multiple inheritance can often be very useful, and I think for this (rather contrived I'll admit) example it makes a lot of sense, taking my previous points into consideration.

Comment: I thought of the Specific interface as extending ICommon. Thus whoever uses them has access to all the methods in ICommon (plus the specific part). How would you achieve that without having the Specifics derive from ICommon ? About CommonImp - of course this is a contrived minimal example. In the actual code there's some meaningful functionality there.

Comment: One option is to make `CommonImp` a member and add a `getCommon` method to `ISpecific1` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very hard to infer design, analysis, requirements and intent from code or short descriptions. Since we don't have much access to those things we can only comment (and maybe answer) using the information give to us, which I did in my comment. Don't take it badly you post a valid question but it's also one that is very hard to both write and answer.

Comment: Do you really need a class that exposes both SpecificImp1  and SpecificImp2 ?

Comment: You can use runtime time polymorphism without inheritance, q.v. [Better Code: Runtime Polymorphism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGcVXgEVMJg) by Sean Parent at NDC 2017.  It's a little mind-blowing.  C++ supports the implementation quite well, but doesn't provide any syntactic sugar — so there's a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: @Yves Daoust - I don't have such a class. They expose either ISpecific1 or ISpecific2, but both of these interfaces share a common part.

Comment: Just declare two classes derived from CommonImp then.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I tried to make the example as minimal as possible. In the real system there's a place for having abstract interfaces (due to more than one potential implementation). So the hierarchy of the interfaces (or something equivalent) is a must for me.

Comment: @Eljay - thanks. It's a nice video. I was actually familiar with the pattern of type erasure in this way. Hesitated to apply it exactly because of the reason you mentioned - lots of builerplate.

Comment: Just my experience, but doing things for "convenience" rarely pays off.  Splitting out ICommon and doing whatever inheritance from it separately may pay off in reduced complexity.  It might make ICommonImp seem more reasonable.  Also, does any of this require runtime type deduction, or can it be done at compile time?  If the latter, try templates instead.  It is mindblowing, but works really well when it does work.

Comment: @casualcoder - thanks I'll think about it. Maybe I can get by with compile time. At the moment it is sufficient, but I have to consider future requirements.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you don't need the two interfaces in the same class, why worry ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust I don't need the two interfaces in the same class. But I do need both an extended interface (e.g. `ISpecific1`) and a base interface impelmentation (`CommonImp`). Since both derive from `ICommon` I have the issue of multiple inheritance. Based on the comments above, my solution might be OK, but I wanted to check for alternatives.

Comment: @wohlstad: I don't see any multiple inheritance here.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: `struct SpecificImp1 : public ISpecific1, public CommonImp`, and both base classes derive from `ICommon`

Comment: Does CommonImp have to derive from ICommon ?

Comment: Yes, its purpose is to implement ICommon.

Comment: You could do: `struct SpecificImp1 : public ISpecific`. Then store `CommonImp` as a member and delegate all calls to it for all `ICommon` methods. There is a bit of boilerplate, yes. But with inheriting from `CommonImp` you are exposing an implementation detail rather than just an interface.

Comment: Thanks @Dean Johnson. It was actually suggested above. It is certainly an option.

Comment: Solution: Do not let `ISpecific1` and `ISpecific2` inherit from `ICommon`. As long as `Specific1` and `Specific2` inherit directly from `ICommon` or indirectly from it over `CommonImp`. Do you have code, which converts between pointers to classes implementing the interfaces (converting from specific to common)? This you could solve with a member function in the specific interfaces (returning the common interface). Or do you want to prevent a class from implementing the specific interface and not the common one? The same, you could not return the common interface without inheriting from it. qed

Comment: @Sebastian not sure I understand. `ISpecific1`, `ISpecific2` are interfaces extending ICommon interface. How can I avoid them inheriting it ? (in the current design). Also I don't have code that needs converting from `ISpecific1` to `ICommon`. But how does it help ?

Comment: I do not know your actual interfaces. What is the dependency of the specific interfaces on the common one? Can't you just write the additional functions into the specific interfaces or do you refer back to a declaration in the common interface from there? Logically you are extending the *interface*, but also programmatically? Perhaps it is enough, if the implementations inherit between specific and common, not the interfaces.

Comment: Now I understand. But in the actual case ICommon contains a lot more than 1 method. All of them should be supported by `ISpecific1`, `ISpecific2` which makes inheting from it very natural and elegant in some way.

Comment: Nevertheless try to do without interface inheritance => no diamonds. Or create the member function in the specific interfaces returning the common interface. All your specific implementations would have to provide a common interface (meaning: they would have to inherit from the common interface). It would be a soft way to enforce it (soft: the implementations theoretically could just return something else than `this`).

Comment: I think it's similar to option #1 in the answer that I posted below (with a summary of the ideas).

Comment: Yes, similar, but the implementation can provide both, the specific and the common interface, without resorting to a member. So less indirection and no code duplication.

Comment: So maybe I didn't fully get your idea. Can you supply a minimal code sample ? You can also post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As modification of point 1 in your answer, you do not have to make `CommonImp` a member nor duplicate anything:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


struct ICommon
{
    virtual void DoCommon() = 0;
};

struct ISpecific1
{
    virtual void DoSpecific1() = 0;
};

struct ISpecific2
{
    virtual void DoSpecific2() = 0;
};



struct CommonImp : public ICommon
{
    virtual void DoCommon() override { std::cout << "CommonImp::DoCommon" << std::endl; }
};

struct SpecificImp1 : public ISpecific1, public CommonImp
{
    virtual void DoSpecific1() override { std::cout << "SpecificImp1::DoSpecific1" << std::endl; }
};

struct SpecificImp2 : public ISpecific2, public CommonImp
{
    virtual void DoSpecific2() override { std::cout << "SpecificImp2::DoSpecific2" << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
    SpecificImp1 si1;
    SpecificImp2 si2;
    si1.DoCommon(); // 1.
    si2.DoCommon(); // 2.

    { // begin new scope to make sure the addresses stay valid
        std::vector<ICommon*> imps;
        imps.push_back(&si1); // 3.
        imps.push_back(&si2); // 4.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This solves the general requirement. No virtual inheritance for the specific interfaces needed, no diamond inheritance.

However, in the code above, it is not enforced by the specific interfaces that the specific implementations also have to provide the `ICommon` interface. But it is indirectly enforced by various usages: By calling `DoCommon()` in 1. and 2. and by converting the address ob the specific objects to `ICommon*` in 3. and 4. So the simplest solution would be to leave it at that.

We can (to a degree) enforce the inheritance of `ICommon` even within the specific *interfaces* by demanding a member function `getICommonP`, which returns an `ICommon` pointer (see code below). The specific implementations inheriting from `ICommon` would just return `this`. The compiler would throw an error, if this abstract member function is not implemented. This function has the added benefit of making it possible to convert from a specific interface to the common interface (5. and 6.). The specific implementation can be directly converted (3. and 4.), because it inherits from `ICommon`. See lines marked with '// added'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


struct ICommon
{
    virtual void DoCommon() = 0;
};

struct ISpecific1
{
    virtual ICommon* getICommonP() = 0; // added
    virtual void DoSpecific1() = 0;
};

struct ISpecific2
{
    virtual ICommon* getICommonP() = 0; // added
    virtual void DoSpecific2() = 0;
};



struct CommonImp : public ICommon
{
    virtual void DoCommon() override { std::cout << "CommonImp::DoCommon" << std::endl; }
};

struct SpecificImp1 : public ISpecific1, public CommonImp
{
    virtual ICommon* getICommonP() override { return this; } // added
    virtual void DoSpecific1() override { std::cout << "SpecificImp1::DoSpecific1" << std::endl; }
};

struct SpecificImp2 : public ISpecific2, public CommonImp
{
    virtual ICommon* getICommonP() override { return this; } // added
    virtual void DoSpecific2() override { std::cout << "SpecificImp2::DoSpecific2" << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
    SpecificImp1 si1;
    SpecificImp2 si2;
    {
        std::vector<ICommon*> imps;
        imps.push_back(&si1); // 3.
        imps.push_back(&si2); // 4.
        ISpecific1* si1p = &si1;
        ISpecific2* si2p = &si2;
        imps.push_back(si1->getICommonP()); // added 5.
        imps.push_back(si2->getICommonP()); // added 6.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A more natural member function would be the conversion operator `virtual operator ICommon&()` within the interfaces instead of `virtual ICommon* getICommonP()`, but some compilers deliver a warning, when your implementations also inherit from the same class, because the conversion to references to base classes is done automatically in this case without calling the explicit conversion operator member function.

On a side note: The specific interfaces are compatible with the solution in point 1 in your answer (except the common interface forwarding): Instead of a pointer to the class itself ('this') the `getICommonP()` functions would return a pointer to the `ICommonImp` member. The implementation could decide, how to implement and provide the common interface - inheriting from it or keeping the common implementation as member variable.

If you do not like an added member function, an alternative for enforcing inheritance of the specific implementations from the interface `ICommon` within the specific interfaces would be to make the specific interfaces into templates and inheriting from them with:

```
struct SpecificImp2 : public ISpecific2<SpecificImp2>, public CommonImp
```

Then `template<class T> Ispecific2<T>` could test (or require), whether `T` inherits from `ICommon` and from `ISpecific2<T>`.

This would go into the direction of point 3 in your answer.

As you now have not one `Ispecific2`, but many `ISpecific2<>` (because of it being a template) - and you often need one interface, you could have all the templated classes `ISpecific2Templ<>` inherit from the same actual specific interface `ISpecific2`.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. Interesting ideas. The only issue I have with your 1st code snippet is that the relation between ICommon and ISpecific1/2 (being that ISpecific1/2 extend ICommon) is not well expressed. This is addressed to some extent in the 2nd code snippet, because having the method `getICommonP()` create a bond between them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a summary of the ideas I got from the comments, in case it's ever usuefull to anybody.

There are some alternatives that will rid me of the multiple inheritance:

1. Simplest alternative:
   `SpecificImp1`,`SpecificImp2` will inherit only `ISpecific1`, and they'll keep `CommonImp` as a member.
   Then they will implement all methods of `ICommon` by delegating to the `CommonImp` member.

   The only downside is the need to duplicate the ICommon implementation in `SpecificImp1`,`SpecificImp2`
   (although it's a trivial duplication - just forwardind to the member).
2. Use type-erasure techniques to achieve polymorphism without inheritance.

   Some examples here: [C++ 'Type Erasure' Explained](https://davekilian.com/cpp-type-erasure.html)

   An interesting video: [polymorphism without inheritance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGcVXgEVMJg)

   The downside is quite a lot of builerplate code.
3. Other template based techniques.

   Maybe use the CRTP pattern ([Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)),
   To achieve sort of compile time polymorphism.

   I still have to think about this direction.

Thanks for the ideas.