# In C++ is there a way to to only allow a class to implement a certain interface as long as it also implements another certain interface?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I'm trying to figure out a way to only allow a class to implement a certain interface (class with all pure virtual functions) as long as it also implements another certain interface.

As an example, in the diagram below, the GoldenRetriever class would have to implement the IDog interface in order to also implement the ISitBehavior interface.

[image]

There would be an error when you tried to implement ISitBehavior without implementing IDog. Or trying to implement interfaces that don't "belong" to the IDog interface.

[image]
[image]

**Is there a good way in C++ to put these restrictions on interface implementation in C++?**

One of the more promising ideas I've had is to use more of a strategy pattern and make member variables in the Dog and Bird interfaces that would point to concrete instances of the behaviors like so:

[image]

However with a large program that would lend itself to having to write a lot of classes per type of Dog or Bird instead of just having one concrete class.

Comment: If implementing `ISitBehavior` requires implementing `IDog` - why not derive `ISitBehavior` from `IDog` ?

Comment: The OP mentioned that "GoldenRetriever class would have to implement the IDog interface in order to also implement the ISitBehavior interface". So I assumed it is the only sitting animal in this domain. If there are other sitting animals, they can all derive from e.g. `ISittingAnimal`, which in turn derives from both `IAnimal` and `ISitBehavior`. Then `IDog ` can derive from `ISittingAnimal`.

Comment: ISitBehavior should be implementable without any restriction if a class just needs that (e.g. a robot). Also, there are other animals that sit, even most birds

Comment: @wohlstad I've also thought of that. However if I have two behaviors derived from `IDog` such as `ISitBehavior` and `IWagTailBehavior` for example and had `GoldenRetriever` implement both of those behaviors, then I have a Diamond in the class heirachy. I know it's possible to use `public virtual` to take care of the problems that come with that, but I'd like to avoid any general no-nos like that.

Comment: @stefaanv Maybe `ISitBehavior` wasn't the ideal name for the example. We could also say `IBarkBehavior`. Only dogs can have the `IBarkBehavior`, but not all dogs necessarily have it.

Comment: @ScottMadeux I understand the hesitation to use diamond multiple inheritance (see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818055/can-you-suggest-an-good-alternative-for-multiple-inheritance-in-this-case). But it seems to fit your needs quite well. You could have ISittingAnimal, IBarkingAnimal, and then some dogs will derive both.

Comment: "Only dogs can have the `IBarkBehavior`, but not all dogs necessarily have it." -- So you have an `IDog` and an `IBarkingDog : IDog`?

Comment: @ScottMadeux even so, whoever uses the IBarkbehavior shouldn't be aware what kind of class is barking.

Comment: Thinking about the answer to @wohlstad 's question that they linked. Would it be a bad idea to have a pure virtual function in `IBarkBehavior` that looked like this `virtual IDog* validateisIDog() = 0;` and then say that that function should always be implemented as just `return this;` and then called in the constructor in the `GoldenRetriever` or other concrete classes? I like it, but it might leave a lot of room for error.

Comment: You’re putting the cart before the horse here. Usage should drive the creation of your interfaces, not the other way around. To put it another way, if your program never treats a goldenretriver like an ibark, then what does it matter if it does or doesn’t implement it? If your program _does_ treat it like one, if you fail to include it, you will get a compiler error, thus securing the guarantee you’re looking for.